# Conan adding a dot in the middle of a path during installation

Tags: c++, windows-10, conan

I'm experiencing a weird issue with Conan while trying to install something.

After installing the packages Conan yields the next error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\{USERNAME}\.conan\data\IOSS\7.0.0\Compass\Release\package\e0698b86d575a60ad0dc25e6cb03ccfbd2f6b04f\.\IOSS\Docs\Generated\html\struct_f_a_c_e_1_1_i_o_s_s_1_1_precision_synchro_1_1_i_o___p_a_r_a_m_e_t_e_r___t_r_a_n_s_a_c_t_i_o_n___t_y_p_e-members.html'

The weird part is that the dot (…b04f\\.\\IOSS…) before \IOSS does not exists and if I remove the dot and check the path manually the path is valid.

[image]

It never happened before and I couldn’t resolve it after trying different things like:

•    Enabling the use_always_short_paths = False variable in the Conan config file

•    Restarting the computer

•    Upgrading the Conan version

•    Enable the windows NTFS long path

It'll be great if someone can explain me the situation or even help me figure it out.

Comment: If you must post a screenshot of text please at least make sure it's legible (but much better to just post text as text)

Comment: yes you are right, i haven't noticed it i will replace for a better quality picture

Comment: your username seems to be 12 characters long which would make the path with the dot 261 characters which is more than `MAX_PATH`, the dot isn't incorrect it just happens to make the path slightly shorter when you remove it, either disable the `MAX_PATH` limit in windows or set conan to use short paths (which I think it does by default?) https://docs.conan.io/1/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#short-paths-reference

Comment: I tried both ways before posting this question as i mentioned still didn't helped 
funny thing is when i try on a different computer it works

Comment: Try bu using short paths instead: https://docs.conan.io/1/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#short-paths

Comment: Unrelated quick hint: Conan package names must be lowercase in 2.0, I'd suggest starting using package names in lowercase as soon as possible. Otherwise, yes, it seems it is hitting the path limit, you would need to enable the ``short_paths=True`` and do not deactivate it globally with configuration.

Comment: Yeah you were right, setting the use_always_short_paths to True has solved it, when I encountered it i thought that just disabling the comment should be enough but apparently now. @uilianries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `use_always_short_paths` variable in the conan.conf file to `True` was the right solution

Answer (score 1):

You can try to update to conan version 2, this should solve your problems with path length on Windows:

> The Conan cache has been completely redesigned to allow storing more
> than one revision at a time. It has also shortened the paths, using
> hashes, removing the need to use short_paths in Windows.

Source: https://docs.conan.io/2/whatsnew.html#multi-revision-cache

You can update your current conan version following the instructions: https://docs.conan.io/2/installation.html#update